# jquery sortable with table and tr width not working in aps.net mvc view

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor, jquery-ui-sortable

I am using jQuery UI sortable to make my table grid sortable. the code does not display any errors however the sortable function does not seem to be working. by this i mean my elements are not reordering. I never used this method in a mvc ( views/razor) project.

would appreciate if anyone can give me some guidance or help.

thank you.

```
script type="text/javascript">

$('td, th', '#MenuItem').each(function () {
    var cell = $(this);
    cell.width(cell.width());
});

$('#MenuItem tbody').sortable().disableSelection();
```

```
<table id = "MenuItem"  class="promo full-width alternate-rows" style="text-align: center;">  
            <tr>
                <th>Prode Code
                </th>
                <th>ProdeTemplate
                </th>
                <th>Description <!-- JACK EDIT -->
                </th>
                <th>Action</th>
            </tr>
            <tbody>
            @foreach (var item in Model.IndexListitem)
            {


                <tr>
                    <td class="center-text">
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ProductCode)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ProdeTemplate.Description)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Description)
                    </td>

                    <td class="center-text nowrap">
                        @Html.ActionLink(" ", "Edit", new { id = item.ProdeID }, new { title = "Edit", @class = "anchor-icon-no-text edit" })
                        @Html.ActionLink(" ", "Details", new { id = item.ProdeID }, new { title = "Details", @class = "anchor-icon-no-text details" })
                        @Html.ActionLink(" ", "Delete", new { id = item.ProdeID }, new { title = "Delete", @class = "anchor-icon-no-text delete" })
                    </td>
                </tr>

            }

                </tbody>

        </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question/code correctly you want to make entire table rows draggable?

The fact that it's in an MVC project doesn't matter.

Always make sure that the page is ready for you to start manipulating elements using [(document).ready()](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/).

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#MenuItem tbody').sortable().disableSelection();
});
```

Here's a [working jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kf61uucy/2/) of what I think you are trying to achieve.